# Организация переодических запросов к серверу

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-service, retrofit2

Здравствйте. Пишу приложение, которое включает в себя сервис, который должен делать переодические запросы к серверу вне зависимости от того, открыто приложение или нет. Как я понимаю, такое можно достичь лишь в том случае, если сервис будет работать в отдельном потоке. Для этого прописал в манифесте:

```
android:process=":service"
```

Сервис работает, все хорошо. Но тут возникает вопрос, как отправить данные активности? Ведь локальный биндинг не работает. На данном этапе я использую класс Messenger и подход, описанный в документации. Вроде бы все хорошо. Но возникла проблема с кнопкой обновления. Переодические запросы на сервер я организовал с помощью ScheduledExecutorService:

```
for(MyRunnerRequests request : listRunners)
            execSerivce.scheduleWithFixedDelay(request, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

В чем, собственно, вопрос. Как организовать внеплановый запрос на сервер? Допустим, если пользователь нажал кнопку "Обновить"? Есть ли какой-то способ сообщить ScheduledExecutorService, что я хочу выполнить задачу раньше указанной задержки, а потом чтобы все шло как прежде? Или просто сделать разовый запрос, который не будет иметь отношения к объекту вышеуказанного класса?

Если у вас есть примеры или опыт работы с подобными сервисами, будь то новостные приложения, месенджеры и т.п. Опишите, пожалуйста, как там организовано переодическое обновление данных и т.д. А так же, мне очень важно понять, как с таким раскладом дел отправить объект имеющегося класса из Service в Activity. Спасибо за ваше внимание и помощь.